# why is array returned as string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mongoose-schema

the create.vue component submits an array where the data property of chartLabels is defined as an array.

```
  data() {
    return {
      report: {
        licenseUsage: {
          chartLabels: [],
}
...
```

Mongoose Schema defines the data type as an array

```
const ReportSchema = Schema(
    {
      licenseUsage: {
        chartLabels: Array,
      },
```

API to create the report is

```
app.post("/api/create", (req, res) => {
  const report = new Report({
  licenseUsage: {
      chartLabels: req.body.licenseUsage.chartLabels,
}
...
});
  report.save(err => {
    if (err) return res.status(404).send({ message: err.message });

    return res.send({ report });
  });
```

the get request with axios is

```
    created: function() {
      this.getReport();
  },

    methods: {
    getReport() {
      axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/report/" + this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
        this.report = response.data.report
        const { chartLabels } = response.data.report.licenseUsage
        this.chartLabels = chartLabels
        console.log(chartLabels)
      });
    },
    },
```

if I inspect the console the form the input field type is an array

[image]

as soon as i click in the form and type 3, 50, 56, 53, 3, 4 inspect console changes to a string

[image]

axios returns the data as a string in an array

```
["3, 50, 56, 53, 3, 4", __ob__: Observer]
0: "3, 50, 56, 53, 3, 4"
```

why am i getting an array of 1 string? I would expect to get an array 6 items like so.

```
Array(6)
0: 3
1: 50
2: 56
3: 53
4: 3
5: 4
```

thanks for any help

--edit

if the array is hard coded instead of defined as an empty array like so it works an array of 6 items is returned.

```
chartLabels: [3, 50, 56, 53, 3, 4]
```

Maybe the question is how to return an array from a single form input field?

Comment: `axios returns the data as a string` ... so, are you saying `response.data` is a string

Comment: yes response.data is a string but needs to be an array

Comment: so, your code fails, right?

Comment: post your api implementation, it pretty likely you just return a string.

Comment: the API was added above. @appleapple and learned it the array is hard coded - defined as a default value it works - an array of items s returned.  I am trying to use a single input form field to get the data

Comment: @Gosmith then please do add the relevant codes (the form, and how it's posted to server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you are **giving** it **a string** value when you enter your [cit.:] "form and type 3, 50, 56, 53, 3, 4".

All input data default to *strings* unless otherwise specified, and it must be done explicitly!

In earlier than HTML 5 a string type of data was all you can put/get. Now among many other new input properties you can have: `<input type="number">`, but there's no such thing as input type = "array".

So instead, you need to *convert* your input data to an **array** object, before feeding it to the monster.
The easiest way to do that is:

```
"3, 50, 56, 53, 3, 4".split(",");
>> [ 3, 50, 56, 53, 3, 4 ]
//WARNING: each 'number' will be a string of course!
```

Comment: To convert these strings to numbers, just `"3, 50, 56, 53, 3, 4".split(',').map(Number);`

Comment: that's fine but, maybe he doesn't need the array members to be of type number

Answer (score 0):

Try to JSON.decode() your response

Comment: So, sorry but in PHP, there's no `JSON.decode()`, it is `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who may find this @window.document & @apple apple had the answer - the question was where to split before feeding the monster. The .split goes in the API like so.  Now returns arrays as strings or numbers on create.

```
app.post("/api/create", (req, res) => {
  const report = new Report({
    month: req.body.month,
    licenseUsage: {
      chartLabels: req.body.licenseUsage.chartLabels.split(','),
      nyRevit: req.body.licenseUsage.nyRevit.split(',').map(Number)
    }
```

but **IS NOT Working** in Update -  the error is .spit is not a function becausean array is returned not a string - yet when the update is saved it get turned back into a string. To fix that you have to add .toString first

```
app.put("/api/report/update/:id", (req, res) => {
  Report.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
  { $set: 
    {
     licenseUsage: {
          chartLabels: req.body.licenseUsage.chartLabels.toString.split(','),
          nyRevit: req.body.licenseUsage.nyRevit.toString.split(',').map(Number)
        }
```